# selecting the latest transaction done in the table

Tags: mysql

i have this query,

```
$sql = "
          select 
            old_team_id
          from
            transfers
          where
            player_id = $player_id and
            transferid = latest_transfer_id
      ";
```

i have a table called transfers, in my table there is `transferid` field, what I want is when I run the query, it will select the `old_team_id` from `transfers` table where the `transferid` is the latest transferid. will that be possible? if yes, what do i lack on my query. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the value in the row with the largest `transferid` you can use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT old_team_id
FROM transfers
WHERE player_id = $player_id
ORDER BY transferid DESC
LIMIT 1
```